# Are LCD/Plasma/Smartphone monitors susceptible to EMR eavesdropping?

Tags: emc

Having just read about EMR[Tempest](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/T/Tempest.html) eavesdropping; I find myself wondering whether

- EMR eavesdropping is defeated by FCC regulations on interference
- With the advance of technology from CRT to the newer LCD/Plasma monitors, hand-held devices/tablets equipped with a touch-screen and such are as susceptible to EMR eavesdropping as the old CRT monitors.

Thoughts, please?

Answer (score 1):

LCD has been shown to be susceptible to Tempest attacks at least http://www.omninerd.com/articles/TEMPEST_Attack_on_LCD - by listening on the signal that was transmitted in the wire to the monitor ... that might work on a plasma as well (but this might not work for like a TV if there are no cables that can leak information)

Comment: Any thoughts about tablet/smart-phone screens? Having experienced interference on a CRT TV when an adjacent tablet rings, I would guess they are susceptible too ...